# XSLT write to same attribute from multiple template matches

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, dita

I have XML that uses a number of custom attributes, but when round-tripping to standard output (DITA in this case), I need to push values from multiple custom attributes into the same single output attribute. These values may come from templates that match the element itself or one of its ancestors.

Here is a simplified example:

```
<concept>
    <title>Test concept</test>
    <conbody>
        <p>Info valid for everything and everyone</p>
        <p brand="product1">Some product-specific info here</p>
        <p brand="product2" country="NL">Even more specific info</p>
        <p country="NL">And this is merely localised stuff</p>
    </conbody>
</concept>
```

The result of my transform should be valid DITA, which would look like this:

```
<concept>
    <title>Test concept</test>
    <conbody>
        <p>Info valid for everything and everyone</p>
        <p props="brand(product1)">Some product-specific info here</p>
        <p props="brand(product2) country(NL)">Even more specific info</p>
        <p props="country(NL)">And this is merely localised stuff</p>
    </conbody>
</concept>
```

When I try to write into the same attribute from various template matches (each one matching one single attribute on any node), only one value appears in the output. I could rework the template to use two passes but in some cases I would need three, or even more, which makes it really complicated. Creating more specific templates that fire when one, or two, or more attributes exist that need to be combined into one quickly becomes a huge list of templates.

The easiest method would be to add a value to an attribute that is created by another template, but I am not sure whether that can be done at all in XSLT 2.0 - as the result of one transform is not available for the other. I am not enough of an expert yet to know whether anything exists that helps me create a maintainable XSL. If there is no such option, I guess I will have to create a fairly complicated multi-pass template after all.

Thanks for either a positive answer ("yes, you can do it and here is how") or a negative one ("no, this cannot be done in XSL 2.0").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible, see a possible solution below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[@brand or @country]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="props.value">
                <!-- Complete the list of profiling attributes -->
                <xsl:for-each select="@brand | @ country">
                    <xsl:value-of select="name()"/><xsl:text>(</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>)</xsl:text><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:attribute name="props" select="normalize-space($props.value)"></xsl:attribute>
            <!-- TODO : process non-profiling attributes here... -->
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

See it work here: http://xsltransform.net/bnnZWJ

---

*Side note: my answer differs from @kjhughes in that I only select and process attributes relevant to DITA profiling - you won't need to add `id` or whatever to the `props` attributes.*

Comment: Thanks. I did not think of running a for-each on all the attributes that need to be combined. I like this answer as I do in fact have such attributes on a whole bunch of elements, not just on the <p> of the simplified example.

Comment: @4everJang: Yes, potame's idea to lead with the attributes rather the elements is better if you'll be wanting to do similar transformations for a core set of attributes across lots of other elements.   Please remember to [**accept**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) his answer if it's helped.  Thank you.

Comment: And of course I can use select="concat(name(),'(',.,') ')" to make it less verbose. I adapted the list of attributes to my real-life case and it works beautifully. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Adjust your mental model away from writing from multiple templates to a single attribute value.  Instead, think of what you want the attribute value to be and how you can gather the pieces of the attribute value from parts of the input XML ***from a single location in your XSLT***.

Most of your output should be the same as your input, so start with the identity transformation.  Then write a special case template for `p`, where you can create its special `@props` attribute by iterating over the input `p` element's attributes.

Here're the basics...

**Given your XML input,**

```
<concept>
    <title>Test concept</title>
    <conbody>
        <p>Info valid for everything and everyone</p>
        <p brand="product1">Some product-specific info here</p>
        <p brand="product2" country="NL">Even more specific info</p>
        <p country="NL">And this is merely localised stuff</p>
    </conbody>
</concept>
```

**this XSLT 1.0 (or 2.0) transformation,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p[@*]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="props">
        <xsl:for-each select="@*">
          <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
          <xsl:text>(</xsl:text>
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          <xsl:text>)</xsl:text>
          <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**will yield this XML output,**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<concept>
    <title>Test concept</title>
    <conbody>
        <p>Info valid for everything and everyone</p>
        <p props="brand(product1)">Some product-specific info here</p>
        <p props="brand(product2) country(NL)">Even more specific info</p>
        <p props="country(NL)">And this is merely localised stuff</p>
    </conbody>
</concept>
```

**as requested.**